How does a computer/microprocessor understand the mnemonics(assembly language) written by a programmer?
I was reading the book "Microprocessor architecture, programming and applications with the 8085" written by Ramesh Goankar. In that I came across the section which deals with how assembly language and machine code wroks(like a brief intro). So here's what I understood:

First, the programmer has to enter the mnemonics specific to the
processor through the ascii keyboard.
Second, the ascii keyboard decodes the character to binary(which
represents the ascii characters .i.e. the mnemonics).
Third, the assembler(specific to the processor) converts the ascii
character to the machine code based on the mnemonics it has provided.
Finally, the machine code is executed.

Is there anything wrong about what I understood? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Not sure what you mean by "the ascii keyboard decodes the character to binary", can you elaborate?

"the assembler converts the ascii character to the machine code" - not sure if a typo or a mistake in your understanding, but a mnemonic consists of multiple characters that would be converted to code, not just a single one. Also there's not just the mnemonic for the opcode in an instruction, also the arguments which would have to be included in the conversion (translation) to machine code

"Finally, the machine code is executed" - typically, the assembler reads the file with the code, and writes another file with the machine code program. That can then be executed at an arbitrary time.

The machine code is executed in two ways: For simple instructions the bits of the machine code directly control execution. E.g. select a source register. For more complex instructions the processor detects the instruction and starts to run so called microcode, which is like a sub-program running inside the processor, which in turn comprises simpler instructions. There is a special memory in the processors for it. E.g. a division or an interrupt or exception could be a more complex instruction.

The assembler also determines memory addresses, e.g. for jump=branch instructions, it calculates the source and target location and the difference in bytes. Or also for reading and writing data it keeps track of the memory adress of variables. In the mnemonic the variables have names, in the machine code they are numeric addresses.

Depending on the keyboard the keyboard either sends the ascii code (like mainframe consoles or ssh), but today more commonly a key number. And the operating system on the computer does the translation. The difference can be for example seen by which system chooses a keyboard layout (for different countries) or which system decides that pressing the shift key creates uppercase characters.

Doing those steps inside the operating system is more comfortable. You can press a modifier key like ALT once, and the menu opens. With old consoles a modifier key without any other key did just nothing. Games can register each key press and release of any key instead of relying on repeated letters.

As to how the assembler converts mnemonic text to an instruction, usually it will be driven by a number of tables which describe the assembly language. The conversion is done by a table lookup of the mnemonic and further by parsing parameters, which can be register names, numbers, equates, or labels.

If you are deeply interested in those topics, look at the nand2tetris lectures, where in a guided way, you will create everything yourself, from the hardware level in the form of logical gates over assemblers and compilers to high level programs: https://www.nand2tetris.org

Your understanding is largely correct.
I would add that each of these steps represent a large chunk of work, rather than operating on one instruction.
Very little ever gets done in one or two assembly instructions.
A programmer writes a whole program or test sequence with intent of running, testing and debugging.
A program consists of many lines of assembly, where each line (modulo directives and blank lines) corresponds to a machine code instruction, including opcode and operands
Program development is a cycle, in that the programmer will often make adjustments to the program, so some editing of assembly text via a text editor, followed by the other steps of build (assemble, link), run & test.

Your understanding is correct ...!
But the system where you are typing your program is also a computer (processor). what you see on the display screen is not exactly a ASCII equivalent of characters you typed , rather its a Pixel representation of character.
Here is the things it will happen internally ...

When you type a program through keyboard , keyboards sends a keystroke to processor and same keystroke's pixel data is sent to display controller by OS to display it on the screen. This is what you see on screen when you type some something.
So far your program is in the text or ASCII format
Assembler interprets each ASCII format mnemonics and convert them to machine readable format, which is Binary in nature.
Now you have data in Binary format, which may be stored somewhere in memory. (If you open Binary file using any editor , what you see on screen is not exactly a Binary at all, its again Pixel representation of each 0's and 1's)
When you execute the Binary, Processor fetches the instructions one by one and produce the desired output.

